# How to build only once using Maven for CI

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration

Im currently reading [Continius Delivery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912) and in the book the author says that it is crucial to build the binarys only once, and then use the same binarys for every deployment. What im having problem understanding is how this can be done in practice? For examaple in order to run the mocked unit tests there would be a special build? What im refering to is the scope tag in Maven.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Maven life Cycle you'll see that you have only one compile task. For your tests, they will be compiled and executed right after the source compilation. With mocked unit tests, it is the same : two separated compilation for two objectives.

I think that the author of your book refers to a problem that may appear when you deploy automatically on several environment : it create more environment to debug. It is compulsory to have only one final binary for all the environment. If you have several binaries that you split over your environment, you can be assured that you will forget what difference there are between two of them, which argument you give to the first one and not the other. For continuous Delivery, it has to be the same everywhere.

Let's come back on Maven. Maven has a lot of possibilities during its life cycle. Sometimes you'll have to run several build to complete everything (as code coverage for example). This may be useful in your continuous integration process and can be done through different build type (every hour for unit test, everyday for code coverage, quality analysis and integration tests).

But in the end, when you'll enter Continuous Delivery, you'll build one final binary, one unique binary copy over your environment